# Не получается осуществить multithreading в питоне/python

Tags: python, многопоточность, клиент-сервер

Есть программа клиент/сервер в питоне. Питаюсь сделать так, чтобы когда один клиент заходит и логинится с помощью имени и пароля, чтобы этот же клиент мог зайти и залогинится из другого места(компьютера, девайса и так далее),вообщем запускаю одну и ту же программу "клиент" с разных папок, но с одним и тем же именем и паролем. "Клиент" заходит с одного места, и сервер принимает имя и пароль. Когда этот же "клиент" заходит с другого места в то же время, сервер отображает новую нить-thread, но строчку пароля не отображает и дальше,соответственно, ничего не идет. Не знаю уже что и как исправить, чтобы один клиент мог логинится одновременно на сервере.

```
# server.py

import socket                                               # Import socket module
import ssl
import sys                                                  # Import system-specific parameters and functions
import hashlib
import os.path                                              # Import module to manipulate paths
import os, time, _thread as thread

from threading import Thread
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
socket.gethostbyname
TCP_IP = 'localhost'
TCP_PORT = 9001
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

def now():
    return time.asctime()

def myrec(the_socket):
    total_data=[]
    while True:
        data = the_socket.recv(8192)
        if not data: break
        total_data.append(data)
    return ''.join(total_data)



class ClientThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self,ip,port,sock):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.sock = sock
        print " New thread started for "+ip+":"+str(port)

    def run(self):
            user_names = []
        passwords = []


            #user_names, passwords = process_file("pass.txt")

            user = self.sock.recv(1024)                        # Get up to 1024 bytes at a time
            print "User: ", user

            try:
        file_conn = open("pass.txt")
        data = file_conn.readlines()

        for i in range(len(data)): 
            if i%2 == 0:
                user_names.append(data[i][:-1])
            else:
                passwords.append(data[i][:-1])

        file_conn.close()
        except:
        sys.exit('There was a problem reading the file!')



            if user not in user_names:
                    self.sock.send ("Unkown User Name, terminating... ")
                    sys.exit('Unkown User Name, terminating... \n')


            else:
                    self.sock.send ("Please enter password: ")
                    password = self.sock.recv(1024)                        # Get up to 1024 bytes at a time
                    print "Password sent to server." + password
                user_input = hashlib.sha224(password).hexdigest()
                    dir_name = ((r'/home/%s') % (user))

                    os.chdir(dir_name)

                    if user_input != passwords[user_names.index(user)]:


               print 'Incorrect Password!\n'
                       self.sock.send ("Incorrect password. ")


               sys.exit('Incorrect Password, terminating... \n')
                    else:

                   print 'User is logged in!\n'
                       self.sock.send ('User is logged in!\n')   

                       filename='se.py'
                       f = open(filename,'rb')
                       while True:
                          l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
                          while (l):
                              self.sock.send(l)
                #print('Sent ',repr(l))
                              l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
                          if not l:
                             f.close()
                             self.sock.close()
            self.sock.close()

tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
tcpsock.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
threads = []

while True:
    tcpsock.listen(5)
    print "Waiting for incoming connections..."
    (conn, (ip,port)) = tcpsock.accept()
    print 'Got connection from ', (ip,port)
    newthread = ClientThread(ip,port,conn)
    newthread.start()
    threads.append(newthread)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
# client2.py
#!/usr/bin/env python


import socket                                                    # Import socket module
import sys                                                       # Import system-specific parameters and functions
import os.path                                                   # Import module to manipulate paths
import ssl
import pprint

TCP_IP = 'localhost'
TCP_PORT = 9001
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

def myrec(the_socket):
    total_data=[]
    while True:
        data = the_socket.recv(8192)
        if not data: break
        total_data.append(data)
    return ''.join(total_data)

print '\nUser & Password Authentication\n'


ssl_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_sock.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

print 'file opened'
user = raw_input('Please Enter User Name: ')
print 'name send to server: ' + user   
ssl_sock.send(user)

data = ssl_sock.recv(1024)
print data

if data == "Unkown User Name, terminating... ":
           sys.exit('Unknown user name, terminating... \n')

else:
          # data = ssl_sock.recv(2048)

           password= raw_input(data)
           print 'pas send to server: ' + password   
           ssl_sock.send(password)

           data = ssl_sock.recv(2048)
           if data == "User is logged in!\n":
              dir_name = ((r'/home/client/%s') % (user))

              os.chdir(dir_name)

              print 'Client is logged in!\n'

              with open('received_file', 'wb') as f:
                  print 'file opened'
                  while True:
                      #print('receiving data...')
                      data = ssl_sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
                      print('data=%s', (data))
                      if not data:
                         f.close()
                         print 'file close()'
                         break
                      # write data to a file
                      f.write(data)


           # print "exit client"

           elif data == "Incorrect password. ":

               # print 'Incorrect password. \n'
              sys.exit('Incorrect password. \n')

           else:
              print "Terminating... \n"


print('Successfully get the file')
ssl_sock.close()
print('connection closed')
```

Comment: Навскидку, во-первых в `python` лучше использовать процессы, а не потоки, в связи с GIL. Во-вторых, например, socket.recv(1024) будет ожидать до тех пор, пока не получит все 1024 байта, или соединение не будет закрыто передающей стороной, но тут могу ошибаться.

Comment: @Nikmoon: для IO задачи (общению по сети) потоки можно использовать. GIL отпускается во время  IO--другие потоки могут выполнять Питон-код, пока текущий поток ждёт окончания IO.

Comment: @Neoni: если цель использования threading, socket напрямую, вместо библиотек более высокого уровня, является образовательной, то начните с более простой задачи: напишите echo сервер: который просто пишет назад всё что получает. Добейтесь, чтобы он у вас работал с несколькими клиентами одновременно. Дополняйте его до тех пор пока он не сломается и этот (упрощённый) код в вопрос добавьте. Рекомендую видео: [David Beazley - Python Concurrency From the Ground Up: LIVE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4) (если на слух не воспринимаете, посмотрите слайды с кодом в описании, попробуйте его)

Comment: вот [код, к упомянутому видео](https://github.com/dabeaz/concurrencylive)

Comment: @jfs спасибо, пойду изучать его код.

Comment: следует подчеркнуть, что этот код строго для образования, чтобы понять как на низком уровне можно несколько вещей одновременно делать. Этот код не следует использовать в рабочем коде. Пример, который можно напрямую использовать это `aiohttp` для http-сервера (и клиента, если хочется), `requests` для http-клиента